# What do you call a glass container containing a large artifact?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call a glass container containing a large artifact? I am wondering if there's a particular name for these things. I thought they were called glass casing, but it seems glass casing is a term used for smartphones.

Comment: That looks like a Centaur in the case!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your photo shows an item in a "display case". You might add a descriptive word/phrase such as "glass display case", "six-foot-tall display case", and so on. "Display case" is what I'd use in US English. There are likely other terms in common use in other regions.